# Unexpected Error: write callback called multiple times executing Gulp.js tasks inside a loop

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to execute some gulp tasks inside a map loop to generate css files for each sass theme I defined. 
Finally, I return all merged tasks with merge-stream package.
Unfortunately, callback seems sent for each iteration / gulp task of my loop and i'm getting the following message : 
Error: write callback called multiple times

```
@Task('build')
build() {
    var self = this;
    var tasks = this.themes.map((theme) => {

        this.foldersXml = getAttributes('jntFolderWithExternalProvider');
        this.filesXml = getAttributes('jntFolder');

        this.foldersXml[theme] = []; this.foldersXml[theme].push(getAttributes('jntFolderWithExternalProvider'));
        this.filesXml[theme] = []; this.filesXml[theme].push(getAttributes('jntFolderWithExternalProvider'));

        fs.readFile(this.themesFolder + '/' + theme + '/' + this.fileName, 'utf8', (err: Error, data: string & Buffer) => {
            if (err) {
                throw new gutil.PluginError({
                    plugin: 'build',
                    message: 'Main file doesn\'t exist for the theme: ' + theme
                });
            } else {
                var vars = data.match(/\$(.*?)\:/g);
                this.requiredVars.map(requiredVar => {
                    if(vars !== null){
                        if(!vars.contains(requiredVar)){
                            throw new gutil.PluginError({
                                plugin: 'build',
                                message: 'Required variable ' + requiredVar + ' is not defined'
                            });
                        };
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return gulp.src(this.templatesFolder + '/' + this.pattern)
            .pipe(header('@import \'' + this.themesFolder + '/' + theme + '/' + this.fileName + '\';'))
            .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', gutil.log))
            .pipe(rename(function (path: any) {
                var file = path.basename + path.extname;

                var folderXml = getAttributes('jntFolderWithExternalProvider') as any;
                folderXml[file] = [ getAttributes('jntCssFile') ];
                self.foldersXml[theme][0][file] = []; self.foldersXml[theme][0][file].push(folderXml);

                var fileXml = getAttributes('jntFolderWithExternalProvider') as any;
                fileXml['jcr:content'] = [ getAttributes('jntRessource') ];
                self.filesXml[theme][0][file] = []; self.filesXml[theme][0][file].push(fileXml);

                path.dirname += '/' + file;
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(this.themesFolder + '/' + theme))

    });

    return merge(tasks);
}

@SequenceTask()
run(){
    return ['build'];
}
```

I just want to get rid of this message and be sure that callback is invoked only at the end. What's the best approach for you ?